# How can I pass variables from a controller to a layout helper in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a quite complex design template, which has different approaches to wrap it's context.

I have to use

```
<body>
  yield
</body>
```

sometimes

```
<body>
  <div class="foo"> 
    yield
  </div>
</body>
```

sometimes

```
<body>
  <div class="bar">
    <div id="breadcrumbs"> 
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="innnerwrap" id="zurb">
      yield
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and so on

I wanna be able to control them from my controller. I thought I make a `template_helper.rb` which decides what to show.

- Any suggestions?
- I also wanna prevent to have 5 or more layouts if only the "wrapper" divs change

Comment: erm sorry, what what has this to do with my question?

Comment: sorry I messed up the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 approaches to this:

1. Set your layout in your controller:

```ruby
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin', :only => [:show, :index]

  # Controller methods
end
```

2. have 1 layout with multiple dynamic partials:

```html
layout.html.erb:
<body>
 <% if params[:controller] == 'MyController' && params[:action] == 'MyAction' %>
    <% render :partial => 'partial1' %>
 <% elsif params[:controller] == 'MyController' && params[:action] == 'MyAction2' %>
    <% render :partial => 'partial2' %>
<% elsif params[:controller] == 'MyController2' && params[:action] == 'MyAction' %>
    <% render :partial => 'partial3' %>
 <% end %>
</body>

_partial1.html.erb
<%= yield %>


_partial2.html.erb
<div class="foo"> 
    <%= yield %>
</div>

_partial2.html.erb
<div class="bar">
    <div id="breadcrumbs"> 
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="innnerwrap" id="zurb">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Anyone know why trying to made these code blocks in my answer is not working?

Comment: hi catfish, so do you think a ```module template_helper```is not a good idea? I thougt a ```content_tag(:div, class:"blubb")``` within a helper would be cool, because I can do some logic on that.

Comment: It probably is a good idea, but I've never done it that way. I suppose you could do something similar to my option 2 in a helper that handles logic as well.

Comment: ok, can you please explain me this ```'partial1' %> 'partial2' %> 'partial3' %> _partial1.html.erb _partial2.html.erb``` chain?

Comment: @Catfish Yes, because you're trying to mix a bullet list and code.